# Function's parameters is Undefined but I called it passing all necessary arguments

Tags: javascript

So I have this pieces of code, what I want to do is parse what is between two words, like:
"Start middle end" should return middle.
If the sentence is "Start middle end. Start middle2 end" it should return an array containing "middle" and "middle2".

**The problem is:**

When I'm invoking the function which is called FindAll, I get and Undefined Object. The Alert which I used to test it also says that any of the parameters is equal to an Undefined Object

You can run it on your firebug and you will see.

```
function findWithin(text, start, end, include) {
    "use strict";
    var stringExists = (text.indexOf(end) === -1),
        startPosition = text.indexOf(start),
        endPosition = text.indexOf(end),
        tMatch = [2];
    tMatch[0] = text.slice(endPosition + end.length, text.length);
    if (!stringExists) {
        if (include) {
            tMatch[1] = text.slice(startPosition, endPosition + end.length);
        } else {
            tMatch[1] = text.slice(startPosition + start.length, endPosition);
        }
    } else {
        tMatch[2] = false;
    }
    return tMatch;
}

function findAll(text, start, end, include) {
    "use strict";
    alert(toString(end));
    var findWithinVar = findWithin(text, start, end, include),
        occurrences = [],
        i = 0;
   // alert(toString(findWithinVar[2]));
    for (i; findWithinVar[2]; i++) {
        occurrences[i] = findWithinVar[1];
        findWithinVar = findWithin(text, start, end, include);
    }
    return occurrences;
}

var text = "Start middle end. Start middle end. Start middle end.",
    start = "Start",
    end = "end",
    result = findAll(text, start, end, false);
```

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight No, it ain't

Comment: I think it isn't because when calling the first function which is called findWithin() it works.

If findWithin() works correctly, I think findAll() should work correctly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `toString` method. It isn't what you think. Just pass `end` to `alert()` instead.

```
alert(end);
```

---

The `toString()` you were using was `window.toString`. I don't know if that's a standard method, but it's basically a shortcut for `Object.prototype.toString`.

When calling `Object.prototype.toStirng`, it expects its `this` value to be some object for which it will return its internal `[[Class]]` property. Because you didn't set the `this` value, it returned `[object Undefined]` since you're in strict mode.

---

If you had done this instead:

```
toString.call(end)
```

it would have returned `[object String]`, which would have been correct, but not what you wanted.

Comment: Well, it is now displaying the correct value passed to the end variable, but my occurrences on the end of the function are still undefined.
But I think it resolves this question. Now I've got another problem.
Thanks for answering my main question, now I've got something else to ask. 
Thanks!